# Does Cognito Forms support integration with Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, cognito-forms

I just created my first form. Now the question is how do I make it available for my staff to use it? We are currently using Google Business apps and I would like to import it into Google Drive.  The therapists would use it to fill in patient info, print it and save the completed form to the patient file.  Is that possible?  How can I do that?

Comment: Please read our [help]. This site is not affiliated with Cognito Forms; it's focus is on answering questions from users of all web apps. Fortunately, the people at Cognito Forms are fairly active here.

Comment: We are planning an update to our support site to provide better guidance to our customers, while still encouraging them to ask "how to" questions like this in a public forum outside of our control. We will definitely increase our user education about how StackExchange works as part of this update.

Answer (score 1):

We are working on releasing support for multi-user organizations, hopefully today or tomorrow, which will allow you to invite other members of your staff to [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) within a single organizational account.

Also, we have lots of customers using our Zapier integration to push entries from Cognito Forms into Google Sheets or uploaded files into Google Drive.  You can learn more about this in our announcement blog post:

http://blog.cognitoapps.com/connect-your-cognito-forms-to-almost-anything-with-zapier

Comment: Our release was live as of last night.  You can now invite anyone to join your organization.